# Change language code within URL javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I have common header file includes navbar in which have multilanguage dropdown.
when i select dropdown language, translates page without any issues.
But when i move to other pages, if should reflect the language selected on first page (eg) if `th` is selected on first page, other page should be `/th` instead of '/en'
currently common header file is always `/en`, when i chose dropdown how i update `a href links` javascript

need to update all href links when particular language is selected from dropdown.

```
//header.ejs
<body>
  <nav>
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/en/about" style="margin-right: 1.5rem!important;">about us</a>//change this link
          </li>
          <li class=" nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/en/contact"
              style="margin-right: 1.5rem!important;">contact us</a>
          </li>//change this link
  </ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="language" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="clickButton()">
        English
      </button>
      <div id="languagelist" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" onclick="clickItem(); return false">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:" onclick="setLanguage('en')">English</a> 
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:" onclick="setLanguage('th')">Thai</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. on `load` see if language is set or not in `cookie`.
2. set selected language in `cookie` on `setLanguage` call.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //read previously set cookie value
    var selectedLanguage = $.cookie( 'selectedLanguage' );
  // 1. on load see if language is set or not in cookie.
     selectedLanguage = selectedLanguage ? selectedLanguage : 'en';
     setLanguage(selectedLanguage);
     
     
     function setLanguage(lan){
        $.cookie('selectedLanguage', lan);
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js" integrity="sha256-1A78rJEdiWTzco6qdn3igTBv9VupN3Q1ozZNTR4WE/Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks lot for reply, i dont know how to change other a href links, if dropdown `th` selected should change all links `/en/about to /th/about `

Comment: can you please help